# npm to install third party conversion tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, esri

I am trying to install a tool that will convert my "feature service" into a geotrigger (something hosted by http://developers.esri.com). I installed node.js and node works just fine, however it seems the manager is missing a file crucial to installing the service I wish to use. Below is the error I get when attempting to follow the install instructions from https://github.com/Esri/featureservice2trigger. There seems to be a missing javascript file.

Do I need to add this? and where would I download or include this file in npm?

I am new to node and have looked at other websites but none seem to document the same type of error I am getting.

```
 nico:~ nroldos$ npm install -g featureservice2trigger

    module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module './polyfills.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nroldos/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:8:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: What node version are you using (`node -v`) ?

Comment: Also, what does `npm -v` say?

Comment: Last login: Mon Apr 28 18:56:40 on ttys000
nico:~ nroldos$ npm -v

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './polyfills.js'....
    
nico:~ nroldos$ node -v
\v0.10.26

Comment: anything involving npm give me that same error, its quite frustrating

Comment: How did you install node? The npm bundled with node v0.10.26 shouldn't have this particular issue any longer. If you used a package manager or brew or something, it's possible that node and npm were separated and you got an older npm version?

Comment: So turns out I needed to remove node from my machine and reinstall it with a version manager (NVM) as opposed to the package/wizard install. I also set the default version to be the most current version of node. Thank you for noting that this problem was most likely based on the version of node and npm, pointed me in the right direction.